# Capacitor Plugins don't work on Android version

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, capacitor

[image]

Hello i am trying to build my capacitor 3 project. It works on iOS just fine but in Android version i am getting errors for all the plugins i am using (like the one on image -Google Sign in) except from the 2 i am declaring on MainActivity.java (FACEBOOK AND FCM).

MainActivity.java

```
package com.myproject.mobile;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
import com.getcapacitor.Plugin;
import com.getcapacitor.community.fcm.FCMPlugin;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         // Initializes the Bridge
        this.init(savedInstanceState, new ArrayList<Class<? extends Plugin>>() {{
        // Additional plugins you've installed go here
        **add(com.getcapacitor.community.facebooklogin.FacebookLogin.class);
        add(com.getcapacitor.community.fcm.FCMPlugin.class);**
      }});
    }
}
```

I am getting a problem report on Visual Studio

```
"message": "MainActivity.java is not on the classpath of project app, only syntax errors are reported",
```

Do i have to declare all the plugins on MainActivity.java? It seems kind of off that's why i am asking.

Plus, the splashscreen jpg works but i am getting the capacitor icon as an app icon.

Any hint?

Comment: What are the specific plugins that are causing issues?  Some plugins are iOS only.  Also, what specific steps did you take to install the plugins?  You may have forgotten to run `cap sync`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I did cap sync every time. No, it's because some plugins are iOS only. I deleted android folder as well and installed capacitor/android and add android again. It should get the plugins from package.json right?

Comment: Also i did Sync Project with Gradle files from Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Try to migrate to Capacitor version 4: [Here's the official guide](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/4-0)

*I was working on google sign-in for so long with capacitor when one day, all of sudden, got multiple errors on Android. What I did notice is that capacitor was just been updated to version 4 and some Android variables needed to change. After I did the upgrade, those error went away.*

Comment: i think its a Webview problem.

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
                ^
  symbol:   method setAppCacheEnabled(boolean)
  location: variable settings of type WebSettings

Comment: Are you using ionic framework with angular?

Comment: If so, I had the same error because I didn't set up the capacitor and google configurations right

Comment: if you mean google sign-in, that's not the only plugin that doesn't work. And i am sure it's a webview thing